# Implementing a programatically created interface in Dojo 1.8

Tags: javascript, dojo, dijit.layout

If I'm looking to implement a cohesive, singular interface concept using Dojo 1.8 dijits, panels, etc for inclusion into pages or other RIA interfaces, what's the best way to architect the implementation?

Let's use a simple login box as an example.  It would be a panel containing two text boxes and a button.  I would **not** be using declarative markup for creating the layout, so no templating.

Potential approaches I've had so far are:

- Extend the panel type I wish to use and then get involved with the dijit lifecycle to ensure it's populated with the controls.
- Extend the Form class and do similar to the last point.
- Create a simple object that just throws everything together and accepts a DOM node to explode onto.
- ???? - I'm not sure of any other options.

Questions:

- Where would event handlers go and how?
- What kind of constructor would I make it have to be as "dojo-ey" as possible for when I'm making use of the encapsulated interface on pages and potentially in other RIA interfaces.

Disclaimer: While I recognize that Dojo tries not to influence these kinds of decisions, I feel like within it's own API there is some sense or opportunity of how to best leverage the  widget lifecycle and class library.  Thus ensuring that my creations are as compatible with other Dojo widgets.